# Does Entity Framework support Encryption

Tags: sqlite, encryption, frameworks, entity

i am using SQLite as the database and Entity Framework to design my database structure.
Needed an info. Does Entity Framework support "Encryption" of a particular column in the database.
Eg: If i have a table T1 with 2 columns C1 and C2. Now if i need to encrypt the data that i stored in C2, then does Entity Framework allows me to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

EF does not directly handle encryption. You'll either enable encryption at the DB level, where I think that SQLite is somewhat lacking in that respect, or you'll have pre-encrypt the data before you persist it to the database using EF.

I would say enabling encryption at the DB level is the best option (also for performance reasons) and I know that SQL CE has support for it but not sure about SQLite. If not, you could easily encrypt before putting data into the database and store it as binary data. Then you can easily get the byte[] with EF.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that there are no other changes needed to your .NET code or connection strings?